# Calcular a média por minuto dos registros no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde um sistema registra número a contagem de peças, porém preciso saber a quantidade média por minuto destes dados, conforme exemplo da tabela abaixo:

```
ID   |    hora   | quantidade
 1   | 09:10:03  |    1
 2   | 09:10:10  |    1
 3   | 09:10:12  |    1
 4   | 09:10:55  |    1
 5   | 09:11:00  |    1
 6   | 09:11:12  |    1
 7   | 09:11:40  |    1
 8   | 09:12:15  |    1
 9   | 09:13:05  |    1
```

Desta forma tenho:

minuto 10 = 4,

minuto 11 = 3,

minuto 12 = 1,

minuto 13 = 1.

Em 4 minutos tive o total de 9 peças com média de 2,25 p/ minuto.
Como trazer em uma única linha esta MÉDIA no MySQL?

Comment: Mais voce que so a media dos 4 minutos ( QuantidadeTotal / Minutos) ou também quer o total de cade minuto individual?

Comment: Neste caso, preciso da apenas da média total de todos os registros da tabela.

Comment: `SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(hora), MAX(hora)) / sum(quantidade) as Media
FROM Tabela`

Comment: Testei `TIMESTAMPDIFF` com uma coluna `DATETIME` mais acredito que deve funcionar para `TIME` tambem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso com a tabela chamada TAB_TMP, o horario ttmp_time e a quantidade ttmp_qte.

```sql
SELECT   
FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ttmp_time)/(1 * 60)) AS time_minute,
COUNT(ttmp_qte) AS quantidade
FROM TAB_TMP
GROUP BY time_minute
```

Resultado:

27196570    4

27196571    3

27196572    1

27196573    1

Se precisa ter resultados cada 5 min (por ex.) basta colocar (5 * 60) etc...

Para ter o resultado esperado ou seja a quantidade por minuto:

```
SELECT  
CAST((COUNT(ttmp_qte)/((FLOOR(MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ttmp_time)/(1 * 60)))+1) - (FLOOR(MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ttmp_time)/(1 * 60)))))) AS FLOAT) AS avg_qte
FROM TAB_TMP
```

Nota que precisa adicionar 1 no "MAX" se não falta 1 minuto no calculo.

Comment: Obrigado Peter, porem nao deu certo. Preciso que retorne a media total dos registros.

Comment: Ah OK. Vou modificar :)

Comment: entendi Peter, agora como que faço para aparecer a media destes registros que seria o 2,25?

Comment: Vejam a função agregada [AVG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg) que é usada para calcular a média dum argumento.